# Run-time error 438 while trying to read Comment property

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to get the text of the Comment (after checking if comment exists) I am getting

> Run-time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

The procedure stops at `s = rR.Comment` when it encounters **the first cell with a comment** in the source worksheet "v".

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
Dim w As Worksheet, v As Worksheet
Dim s As String
Dim rR As Range

Set w = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set v = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
For i = 1 To 10
  For j = 1 To 10
    For c = 0 To 12
      s = ""
      Set rR = w.Cells(i, c + 7)
      With rR
        .ClearContents
        .ClearComments
        .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        v.Cells(j, c + 4).Copy
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        If Not .Comment Is Nothing Then
          s = rR.Comment  ' <============== ### HERE IT STOPS WITH RUN-TIME ERROR 438 ###
          If InStr(1, s, "test") > 0 Then
            .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
            .Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Interior.Color = 13434828
            .Interior.TintAndShade = 0
            .Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
          End If
        End If
      End With
      Set rR = Nothing
    Next c
  Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Does comment have a default property?

Comment: @nicomp - probably yes because in my another procedure, the similar code: `If InStr(1, LCase(w.Cells(i, c).Comment), "test") = 0 Then` works without any error. And as I can see `.Text` is not a property of the Range object - it's a method.

Comment: @McVik again, that is not possible. Most likely you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere just swallowing the error, and the condition is systematically entered, and that is a bug. `Comment` is an object without a default member, your other procedure has a bug. Whether `Text` is a property or a method makes no difference. Avoid implicit default member calls, your code will be much more reliable as a whole.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you are 100% right, it's my fault, I'm sorry. I looked at the older version of the procedure which probably wasn't tested. Now when I started checking that, I found that there aren't some other changes I made to that code and obviously it doesn't work. After making some changes it stopped in this place `If InStr(1, LCase(w.Cells(i, c).Comment), "test") = 0 Then` with the error 438.

Comment: PS. And of course I thought about the Comment object's method, not the Range object.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Rubberduck sounds great. I write a lot of VBA procedures especially in MS Excel to help myself to do automatically many boring and recurrent manual things but I have never heard about this project. Thank you for this hint, I'll try it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing the `.text` from the end.

Try:

```
s = rR.Comment.Text
```

Comment: It helped, thank you @TomClarke, but it looks strange for me while `.Text` is a method not a property of the Range object. And the strangest thing is that in another procedure, the similar code: `If InStr(1, LCase(w.Cells(i, c).Comment), "test") = 0 Then` works without any error.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this on my side, without the `.text` in the Instr I get an error. Strange.

Comment: @McVik `Comment` is an object, and it doesn't have a default member: it is simply impossible that `LCase(w.Cells(i, c).Comment)` ever worked.

Comment: You are right, It's my fault - `If InStr(1, LCase(w.Cells(i, c).Comment), "test") = 0 Then` doesn't work. I looked at untested procedure. I'm sorry for misinforming you. Thank you very much for your help. And of course I thought about the Comment object's method, not the Range object.